# Unlocked package - Can't package with PesonEmail field

Tags: soql, standard-objects, unlocked-package

I am unable to package some sObject & Apex classes with SFDX.

I have this error :

```
No such column 'PersonEmail' on entity 'Account'.
If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to, be sure to append the '__c' 
after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

I use this query :

```
existingAccount = [SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE PersonEmail=:cnt.email]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [PersonAccount](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm#so_personaccounts) support in the [Scratch Org Configuration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm) file, then specify that definition file for the [package configuration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_config_file.htm).

```
{ "features": [ "PersonAccounts" ] }
```

...

```
{ "path": "package/path",
  "default": true,
  "package": "thePackage",
  ...
  "definitionFile": "config/scratch-org-def.json",
  ...
}
```

Once you enable the feature, it should package correctly.

Comment: Yes it works ! thank you a lot ;)